# show data in gridview after selection from dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

[image]Hi i just want to show data in my gridview after selecting value from dropdown list and after selecting my dropdown list when i press on search button data can be seen in gridview. My gridview is connected with my database how can i do that my code is this:

aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Portal" HeaderText="Portal" 
                SortExpression="Portal" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TID" HeaderText="TID" SortExpression="TID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PNR" HeaderText="PNR" SortExpression="PNR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="TicketNumber" 
                SortExpression="TicketNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ESACCode" HeaderText="ESACCode" 
                SortExpression="ESACCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WaiverCode" HeaderText="WaiverCode" 
                SortExpression="WaiverCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" 
                SortExpression="Remarks" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnusedTicketAmount" HeaderText="UnusedTicketAmount" 
                SortExpression="UnusedTicketAmount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlUnusedAmount" HeaderText="ddlUnusedAmount" 
                SortExpression="ddlUnusedAmount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AirlinePenality" HeaderText="AirlinePenality" 
                SortExpression="AirlinePenality" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlAirlinePenality" HeaderText="ddlAirlinePenality" 
                SortExpression="ddlAirlinePenality" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NetRefundProcess" HeaderText="NetRefundProcess" 
                SortExpression="NetRefundProcess" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlNetRefundProcess" 
                HeaderText="ddlNetRefundProcess" SortExpression="ddlNetRefundProcess" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundableCommission" 
                HeaderText="RefundableCommission" SortExpression="RefundableCommission" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ddlRefundableCommission" 
                HeaderText="ddlRefundableCommission" SortExpression="ddlRefundableCommission" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CouponRefunded" HeaderText="CouponRefunded" 
                SortExpression="CouponRefunded" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RefundType" HeaderText="RefundType" 
                SortExpression="RefundType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTime" HeaderText="DateTime" 
                SortExpression="DateTime" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BartConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Test]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

code on aspx.cs page

```
public void GridViewBind()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Test where ID=" +     DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Test");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Test"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GridViewBind();
}
```

After selecting value from my dropdown list Error : Invalid column name 'TRAVELONG'

Comment: Does your SQL database have a column called TRAVELONG? What is the name of the value you are selecting?

Comment: Travelong is item in dropdown list suppose i have Travelong related data in database when i bind gridview with sql it will show data related all the item now i only want to see data related to travelong so i select travelong from dropdownlist and press search button i can view only travelong related data in grid i hope i am clear

Comment: ok i think u got my question can u help me on this @Dave RooK

Comment: But you are passing it as a column

Comment: yes its not c its only a small part of my project so i divide my project into small modules thats why i didn't do that can you tell me how to postit back after updating it

Comment: See Brian's post, this is what I was trying say! ha ha

Comment: ok in place on ID if i put my portal column into the query will it take it coz when i put ID column it showing conversion error that varchar datatype cannot convert into int data type

Comment: You have already Bind your Grid with SQLDATASOURCE1 for which you wrote just a select query without where clause. You should use ControlParameter and set the Dropdownlist SelectedValue property as ControlParameter.

Answer (score 1):

Is ID a string?  If so, you need inner quotes for the ID field:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Test where ID='" +     DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
```

Otherwise, it may be considering the selected value as a column...

Comment: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. if i take Portal column to match with dropdown list it showing both datasource and datasourceID are defind on gridview1

Comment: Let me clear my question again i have a dropdown list with portal in it when i select one of the portal from it it will show data in grid regarding that portal

Comment: OK, I don't understand where the error actually occurs then, it's not in the code sample above??

Comment: shall i send you my database

Comment: No, I see from your post above it's an int, so that's good. But what is DropDownList.SelectedValue?  Is it an int value?  If not, that's the error.  If it is, is the error actually happening on the line I included above?

Comment: no its not an int value it nvarchar i will write my whole code in another question and send u the link then u will analyze it wait

Comment: @brain Mains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640073/show-data-in-gridview-after-selection-from-dropdown-list-connected-with-sql